# Comma or "that"

Tags: commas

A sentence reads:

> Keep in mind the offer ends at the end of the month.

Should there be a comma after "mind," or a "that" inserted between "mind" and "the"? Or is it correct the way it is written?

And what is the reasoning/rule?

Many thanks!

Comment: I think either of your moves would improve the thing, but it is not *wrong* as is (now that I've edited out the redoubled "at," anyhow).

Answer (score 1):

I think "that" is better since you actually have two phrases which you wanted to connect to each other. Although the comma could do the same but usually comma is used when you want to have a bit of pause. Then to read it correctly it should be read like: *Keep in mind, `1sec pause` ...*

With using "that" you also specify which actually should be in mind.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, English being what it is, there is no hard and fast rule. Either of the two corrected options ("mind," or "mind that") would be acceptable. I would tend to write it as "Keep in mind, the offer ends at the end of the month," because it is the most conscise.

Answer (score 0):

All of the options are appropriate.

In English, there is a rule about "implied that" where a phrase can be written without "that" and it is understood to be there.

*We know **that** the sun is not exploding* vs *We know the sun is not exploding.*

It is a matter of preference whether or not to include it, so if you like it better with a directly-stated "that," go for it.

If you choose to use the comma, you are changing the sentence to put more emphasis on the directive instead of keeping an informative tone.